# Framing convergence as a topological question

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits, algebraic-topology

I am taking a course in Algebraic Topology, and we have covered extension problems - that is, questions of the form "Does $f : X \to Y$ extend continuously to a map $\hat{f} : \hat{X} \to Y$ such that $\hat{f}|_{X} = f$ ?".

I was pondering this type of question and came up with this characterisation of a sequence having a limit:

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $\mathbb{N} \stackrel{f}{\to} X : n \mapsto x_n$ a sequence in $X$. Then $(x_n)$ converges if and only if $f$ extends continuously to a map $\hat{f} : \mathbb{N}^* \to X$. Furthermore, if this holds then the limit of $(x_n)$ is $\hat{f}(\infty)$.

(Here $\mathbb{N}^* = \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is the one-point compactification of the naturals.)

My question is if this is actually a characterisation of a sequence having a limit, or if I have missed/assumed something that makes this not work. Also, do generalisations of this to spaces other than $\mathbb{N}$ have any interesting properties?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can replace $\mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ with any compactification of the natural numbers to get other notions of convergence, the maximal one being the Stone-Cech compactification.

Comment: A generalization of sequences is nets.